# Checking if every char in a string belongs to the given set of chars or not (JAVA)

Tags: java

So I need to create a method isValidDNA which works like this:

> public boolean isValidDNA()
>
> Returns true if the DNA is valid, i.e, only contains the letters,
> A,T,C,G (in uppercase) and at least one of these characters.

All I could think of was this, which apparently doesn't work:

```
    public boolean isValidDNA(){
    for (int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
        if (dna.charAt(i)=='A' || dna.charAt(i)=='T' || dna.charAt(i)=='C' || dna.charAt(i)=='G' ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? Where is `dna` declared?

Comment: Why not use a regular expression for this check?

Comment: `return dna.matches("^[ATCG]+$");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a return statement immediately, which will exit during the first iteration and only check the first character.

You need to store this information in a boolean and return it after you've checked the whole string:

```
public boolean isValidDNA(String dna){
  Boolean result = true;
  // Add an extra check for the "at least one character" thing.
  for (int i=0; i<dna.length(); i++){
    if (dna.charAt(i)!='A' && dna.charAt(i)!='T' && dna.charAt(i)!='C' && dna.charAt(i)!='G' ){
        result = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

However, you would be better off using [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for these problems.

Comment: your if-statement won't work this way because you will always return false if you concat with ||. And even with && you will never proof the whole string!

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted his code and forgot to change the operators. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression:- `[ATCG]+` In code this could look like this:

```
public boolean isValidDNA(){
    return dna.matches("^[ATCG]+$")
}
```

Comment: What exactly do the symbols '^' and '+$' mean?

Comment: See the link in my answer for a good guide about Regular Expressions. They are a very powerful tool, but can be a bit confusing to write... And worse to read :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
public boolean isValidDNA(){
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
        if ((dna.charAt(i) != 'A') && (dna.charAt(i)!='T') && (dna.charAt(i)!='C') && (dna.charAt(i)!='G') ){
            res = false;
            break;  
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

if your startpoint is that the DNA is valid, it's much more easy to test if it's really so. You only have to test each char of your `dna` and can stop by the first entry that doesn't satisfy your if-statement.

Comment: But how does that check if every character in the set [A,G,T,C] has been used at least once? Also, is the "break" actually required?

Comment: there's no need for this in your description. "and at least one of these characters." so not all have to appear, but at least one of that four characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using your way, you've almost got it.

Right now, you return `true` if you find one that's OK, and only return `false` if all are wrong. You can negate your `if` condition, and return `false` as soon as you find one that's **not** OK, and only return `true` if all are fine.

I'll leave the coding part up to you.

As others pointed out, regex will be a cleaner solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this implementation.

First declare a constant:

```
private static final String bases = "ATCG";
```

And then use it in the method like this:

```
public boolean isValidDNA() {
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (char c : dna.toCharArray()) {
        if (bases.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Unusual but interesting implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a DNA sequence: ");
seq=sc.nextLine();    
    if(seq.matches(".*[^ATCG].*")){
        System.out.println("Not a valid sequence.");
        System.exit(0);
}
```

This regular expression works so that only sequences containg A,C,T or G with no other charcters, spaces, etc included will continue